# JavaScript [ memory leak ] : animation using javascript causes memory leak

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, memory, memory-leaks

**Problem statement:**
As a developer, I want to develop a typewriting animation effect that should run on the page as long as the page is alive without causing any performance issues on the page (memory leak).

Issue What I'm facing right now is my code is causing a memory leak which I want to avoid.

[image]

This What I have developed so far.

```js
let loopAnimation = true;
let animationTimeout;
let animationBase = 'Develop in ';
let animationPool = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'];
let animationCounter = 0;
let animation = animationBase + animationPool[animationCounter];
let i = 1;

let timeoutReadable = 1750;
let timeoutTyping = 100;
let timeoutDeleting = 70;

let span = document.getElementById('animationtextbox');
let forwarding = false;
let currentWord;

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    animationTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
      return null;
    }, ms);
  });
}

textAnimation();

async function textAnimation() {
  while (loopAnimation) {
    currentWord = null;
    currentWord = animationPool[animationCounter];
    if (forwarding) {
      if (i < currentWord.length) {
        // play effect (type word)
        span.innerText =
          animationBase + currentWord.slice(0, i - currentWord.length);
        i++;
        forwarding = true;
        await sleep(timeoutTyping);
      } else {
        span.innerText = animationBase + currentWord;
        i = 1;
        forwarding = false;
        await sleep(timeoutReadable);
      }
    } else {
      if (i <= currentWord.length) {
        // play effect (remove word)
        span.innerText =
          animationBase + animationPool[animationCounter].slice(0, i * -1);
        i++;
        forwarding = false;
        await sleep(timeoutDeleting);
      } else {
        // switch animation word
        i = 1;
        if (animationCounter < animationPool.length - 1) {
          animationCounter++;
        } else {
          animationCounter = 0;
        }
        forwarding = true;
        await sleep(timeoutTyping);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span id="animationtextbox"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be recursive? You only call `textAnimation()` once, *outside* of the `textAnimation()` call, never inside. (and your `sleep()` function doesn't call itself)

Comment: sorry, my bad phrased the question bit wrong.  animation functionality is looped using while loop

Answer (score 1):

You are not Clearing your timeouts

add

```
await clearTimeout()
```

After every timeout you create

replace your function with

```
async function textAnimation() {
  while (loopAnimation) {
    currentWord = null;
    currentWord = animationPool[animationCounter];
    if (forwarding) {
      if (i < currentWord.length) {
        // play effect (type word)
        span.innerText =
          animationBase + currentWord.slice(0, i - currentWord.length);
        i++;
        forwarding = true;
        await sleep(timeoutTyping);
        await clearTimeout(animationTimeout )
      } else {
        span.innerText = animationBase + currentWord;
        i = 1;
        forwarding = false;
        await sleep(timeoutReadable);
        await clearTimeout(animationTimeout)
      }
    } else {
      if (i <= currentWord.length) {
        // play effect (remove word)
        span.innerText =
          animationBase + animationPool[animationCounter].slice(0, i * -1);
        i++;
        forwarding = false;
        await sleep(timeoutDeleting);
        await clearTimeout(animationTimeout);
      } else {
        // switch animation word
        i = 1;
        if (animationCounter < animationPool.length - 1) {
          animationCounter++;
        } else {
          animationCounter = 0;
        }
        forwarding = true;
        await sleep(timeoutTyping);
        await clearTimeout(animationTimeout);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

actually for a single-page Web App, even using pure CSS code (e.g. "transition: ease 0.2s;"), Chrome will have a memory leak.

so we have no choise to delete all the "transition" in our CSS.

it take a lot of time to find this problem.